# Calculate Shortest Path between two geo points?

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps

Im a new in Java and Android. I need to find Shortest Path between two goepoint.
I have been searching all day for the answer and i just got this code :

```
var directionDisplay;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var map;

  function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom:7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: chicago
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  }

  function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
    var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
    var request = {
        origin:start, 
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        routePath = result.routes[0].overview_path;
        for(var a = 0; a< routePath.length; a++){
          // Your vector layer to render points with line
        }
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
  }
```

The main code is here :

```
      directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                routePath = result.routes[0].overview_path;
                for(var a = 0; a< routePath.length; a++){
                  // Your vector layer to render points with line
                }
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
              }
            });
```

The problem is I want to implement this code in Android. but i dont know how.
Is there anybody know how to change the code so i can use it in Android ?

Here the link source [This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25253/computing-shortest-distance-using-google-map-v3-and-openlayers)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm

Answer (score 2):

**There are two ways to find distance between two GeoPoints :**

1. This **does not use internet connection & uses some mathematics** to calculate the shortest distance between the two points.

   ```
   /**** Method for Calculating distance between two locations ****/
   public float DistanceBetweenPlaces(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, Context cont) {
       float[] results = new float[1];
       Location.distanceBetween(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, results);
       return results[0];
   }
   ```
2. This **uses internet connection & uses Google Maps API** to detect the exact distance between the two points. The code implementing it is below :

   ```
   /**** Class for calculating the distance between two places ****/
   public class CalculateDistance {
        String distance;
        public void calculate_distance(String src_lat, String src_lng, String dest_lat, String dest_lng) {
            distance = getdistance(makeUrl(src_lat, src_lng, dest_lat, dest_lng));
        }

   /**** Method for make URL ****/
   private String makeUrl(String src_lat, String src_lng, String dest_lat, String dest_lng) {
       StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
       urlString.append("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?");
       urlString.append("origins="); // from
       urlString.append(src_lat);
       urlString.append(",");
       urlString.append(src_lng);
       urlString.append("&destinations="); // to
       urlString.append(dest_lat);
       urlString.append(",");
       urlString.append(dest_lng);
       urlString.append("&sensor=true&mode=driving");
       return urlString.toString();
   }

   /**** Method for getting the distance between the two places ****/
   private String getdistance(String urlString) {
        URLConnection urlConnection = null;
        URL url = null;
        try {
             url = new URL(urlString.toString());
             urlConnection = url.openConnection();
             BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

             String line;
             StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
             // take Google's legible JSON and turn it into one big string.
             while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                   sb.append(line);
             }
             // turn that string into a JSON object
             JSONObject distanceMatrixObject = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
             // now get the JSON array that's inside that object
             if (distanceMatrixObject.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("OK")) {
                   JSONArray distanceArray = new JSONArray(distanceMatrixObject.getString("rows"));
                   JSONArray elementsArray = new JSONArray(distanceArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("elements"));
                   JSONObject distanceObject = new JSONObject(elementsArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("distance"));
                   return distanceObject.getString(("text"));
             }
        return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
             return null;
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: The result of the method returns the distance in metres or km. You call the method from your Activity class like this: `private CalculateDistance calcObject = new CalculateDistance();  String final_distance = calcObject.calculate_distance(Source_Latitude, Source_Longitude, Destination_Latitude, Destination_Longitude);`

Comment: sorry but im confuse where should i put my koordinate is it in Method for make URL or in Activity class ?

Comment: You have to put the coordinates in the Activity class from where you are calling the method calculate_distance.

Comment: when i put my coordinate, i got error cause my coordinate is double but the method is string..
can you show me the code please..@ArshadParwez

Comment: @ShintaDwi: You can just type cast your coordinate values from double to String. Simply use `<varible-name>+""`. It will change the double into a String & the method would work.